# Spark: Error while compressing and saving to text file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a scala Spark job. I want to compress the output using Gzip and then saveToTextFile.

```
compressedEvents.saveAsTextFile(outputDirectory, org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec)
```

But I get the following error:

```
[error] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/producer-data-test/producer-data-test-build/src/main/scala/IpFromLogs.scala:46: object org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec is not a value
[error]     compressedEvents.saveAsTextFile(outputDirectory, org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec)
[error]                                                                                       ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I tried different variations of the same but none of them work. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Correct way of saving is

```
compressedEvents.saveAsTextFile(outputDirectory, classOf[GzipCodec])
```

Or 
before you save set the configuration as

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.setClass(FileOutputFormat.COMPRESS_CODEC, classOf[GzipCodec], classOf[CompressionCodec])
```

And save it as

```
compressedEvents.saveAsTextFile(outputDirectory)
```